# Call dynamic variable with webpack without using eval

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to move legacy javascript code over to work with webpack. Unfortunately, I have found that in the legacy javascript, the old way of referencing variables dynamically with 'window[VAR_NAME]' no longer works with webpack. I know that using 'eval(VAR_NAME)' works, but it will exception if the object does not exist, unlike the 'windows[VAR_NAME]' way which can be checked for null.  Is there a better way to call variables dynamically in webpack?

Below javascript code stops working in webpack:

```js
var item1 = 'dog';
var item2 = 'cat';
var item3 = 'mouse';

$(document).ready(function() {
  CallAnimals();
});

function CallAnimals(i) {
  if (i == null) {
    i = 1;
  }
  var currentAnimal = window['item' + i];
  if (currentAnimal) { //can check for null here
    alert(currentAnimal);
    CallAnimals(i + 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `window['item1']` won't exist because the `var item1 = 'dog';` declaration gets wrapped in a module by Webpack, so `item1` won't be a global.

Comment: But I'm calling from within the same module: For example eval('item1') in this case would work. I do understand the window object is no longer relevant when webpack bundles it.

Comment: I see. However, as far as I am aware there is no mechanism for dynamically accessing a simple variable. To access them dynamically, you'd need to make them properties of an object. Prior to your using Webpack, that's what they were: properties of `window`; they weren't simple variables.